# How to get the component reference on click angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-directives

```
<!--snippet from template file-->
<custom-component 
    ... other properties
    (mousedown)="onMouseDown()"
</custom-component>

@Component({
    //selector and templateURL
})
class ContainerComponent{
      onMouseDown(){
          //get the reference to the custom component here
      }
}
```

So I have multiple custom components in my template file pointing to the same `mousedown` event how do I get the reference to the customComponent. I want the real reference to the component not to the native element, I want it to compare it with the @ViewChild() thing.

Comment: What's the relationship between `custom-component` and `ContainerComponent` ?

Comment: ```custom-component``` is the child of ```ContainterComponent``` the custom-component selector is being used in the html file of ContainerComponent

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component,ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

    <!--snippet from template file-->
    <custom-component #start 
        ... other properties
        (mousedown)="onMouseDown()"
    </custom-component>

    @Component({
        //selector and templateURL
    })
    class ContainerComponent{
          @ViewChild('start') start;
          onMouseDown(){
              //this.start holds the reference
              //get the reference to the custom component here
          }
    }
```

Comment: this is not the question,

there are multiple custom-components on the page, having the same mousedown event, how to know which one clicked it?